# Bluetooth devices keep hijacking the other device's connection on Google Pixel 2

Tags: samsung, settings, bluetooth, headphones, google-pixel

On my `Pixel 2` running `Android 10`, in the `Bluetooth` settings, there are several devices listed under `Previously Connected Devices`. My `Bluetooth` headphones are at the top of the list while my car's `Bluetooth` is at the bottom of the list.

I often listen to music on my headphones while walking to my car. When I start my car, my car's `Bluetooth` pairs with my phone and hijacks the audio so that it begins playing through my car's speakers.

Is there a way to establish connection priority with `Bluetooth` on `Android` so that if a higher priority device is already connected, then a lower priority device won't steal the connection?

Or is there a way to turn off auto-connect for some `Bluetooth` devices? After reading this, I assume that there is not: https://support.google.com/android/thread/41125271?hl=en

I'd like to keep my car as a paired device if possible so that if I ever do want to play music through my car speakers, I can manually re-connect to my car without having to pair first.

Comment: You might wish to disconnect your car from your device. I had to do this with one car (now gone) and I do not connect my phone anymore.

Comment: For the last part you can try automation with MacroDroid app, [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltlba.jpg) —haven't tested